# how many users download my IOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics, itunes-store

I want to know the number of users who install my application from itunes store, where can I found it? 
Note: I don't want Google Analytics, I just want the number of users who install it in their devices.
Otherwise, with android applications, you can see the installation and active installations (the number of users who install the application from play store).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can find the number in iTunes Connect.
2. Login to iTunes Connect.
3. Sales and Trends
4. Select the app and you can see daily, weekly and monthly sales/downloads.

However, you won't be able to find out whether they are actively using the application or not.

Comment: I opened the sales and trends page, and I don't understand what I see, for example, in Lebanon I installed it on 3 devices minumum, and what I see in lebanon one unit, what are these units??? see attachment above please

Comment: @Fatima : Unit is number of downloads. If you have installed today it'll reflect tomorrow.

Comment: I have installed two weeks ago, on my ipad and iphone and another ipad

Comment: They you might have to change the week of which data it's displaying. On your top right. There will be date displayed. Click on it and change it to weekly or monthly.

Comment: just one question, if I want to see the total number of units for now, because I publish the application on 19 july so I want the number of users who install it until now included august? how can i see?

Comment: Change the date to monthly and just sum up the total number of downloads.

Comment: Hi again Rushi, can you tell me what are the change column in the chart?

Comment: Change column is nothing but the change in download as compare to last figure. For eg in above chart in Front of UK it says -1. That means last week in UK there were 2 people downloaded the app. But this weeks there was only 1 app downloaded. So, change in app downloaded is -1 and in percentage its -50%(that's half).

Answer (score 5):

Apple just updated https://itunesconnect.apple.com site you can adjust the date range in the middle of screen (using the slider) or by adjusting the dates on top left corner after navigating to sale and trends screen to see how many downloads you have had.
[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, but the new update of sales/trends page is not opening, it is slow and not opening the results, what shall i do??

Comment: @Fatima welcome. It opens but it's just little slow when you click on it. Give it a few minutes and it loads.Also, if you find this useful please give it a vote up