# How to know number of user installed my ios application

Tags: ios, itunes

Can any one suggest,how to know number of users downloaded my iOS app,number of user installed my iOS app,number of users uninstalled my iOS app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056010/how-many-users-download-my-ios-application.....repeated question!

Answer (score 1):

You can see how many different Apple IDs were used to download your app(s) through [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa)'s *Sales and Trends* page. Unfortunately, there isn't really a way to see how many users have uninstalled your app. The reasons for this are:

1. Apple doesn't report it to you
2. Apple doesn't warn the app that it's being deleted before deleting
   it (on the device), therefore the app won't have a chance to send
   some sort of value to your server indicating that the user has
   deleted it

What you can do, however, is see if the user has opened your app and logged in to your server in the last 3 months (for example). If not, you can pretty much assume they've deleted the app.

Third party libraries like [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com) can also be used to track various things in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of downloads  at `sales and trends` in the `iTunesConnect` .
[image]

you cannot track the uninstalls but, you can use some third party libraries for Analytics (ex- Flurry, etc) .

Answer (score 0):

App Analytics in the iTunes Connect website lets you track 'App Units'.

Click the date filter dropdown at the top right and choose a custom range to cover (if possible) your apps' entire history. It only lets you go back to April 2015 (as of Jan 2017) but this was enough for my needs.