# Email ID of user who downloaded my iOS app from iTunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

Hi Anyone please help me on this case,
Is that possible to find the Apple ID or Email ID of user who downloaded my iOS application?

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056010/how-many-users-download-my-ios-application) was helpful to find the number of downloads.
It will be great help if I can see the email ID or Apple ID of user to run particular campaign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get email id of user who downloaded application. If you used email address in your application, then you can use any 3rd party analytics tools and send email Id of user in property. By default Apple is not providing..!!

Comment: Thank you for your timely reply. I surfed about analytics tools such as [Parse] (https://parse.com/) and [Localytics] (http://www.localytics.com/). But it requires a field to get user's Email ID or something like authentication. It will be great if I can get Email ID without asking this to user.