# How to get the Apple ID of user who has downloaded my App from iTunes/App Store

Tags: objective-c, ipa, apple-id

When I am working on an app(call it myApp), a feature needs getting the Apple ID of user who has downloaded myApp from iTunes/App Store.

After a lot of googling, in .ipa package I found "iTunesMetadata.plist" file which contains the AppleID.

There is a demo of "iTunesMetadata.plist" file:
https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki//private/var/mobile/Applications/$uuid$/iTunesMetadata.plist

There are some questions about "iTunesMetadata.plist" file:

A): Which part or Who create this "iTunesMetadata.plist" file in .ipa (Apple or App Developer).

B): I found since iOS8, the location of "iTunesMetadata.plist" file has changed.

iOS 7 and before iOS 7: $(unziped-ipa-file)/Payload/myApp.app/iTunesMetadata.plist

iOS 8 and after iOS 8: $(unziped-ipa-file)/iTunesMetadata.plist

In myApp, Can I read or access this "iTunesMetadata.plist" file in both iOS 7 and iOS 8+ by programming (e.g. reading the "iTunesMetadata.plist" file)?

C): If I delete this "iTunesMetadata.plist" file from installed directory, Would installed app run normally?

[Email ID of user who downloaded my iOS app from iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853325/email-id-of-user-who-downloaded-my-ios-app-from-itunes)

Update 1: 
I use Xcode Archive Ad Hoc Distribution and iOS App Store Distribution, then export .ipa package from these Archives. I find out that there is not "iTunesMetadata.plist" file in this kind .ipa. So, Maybe the "iTunesMetadata.plist" file is created by Apple(iTunes).

Comment: No user details are stored/encoded within the application ipa file. You are unable to get these details with out explicitly asking the user.

Comment: And you can't ask the user without a good reason - it's against the rules.